# Como usar jQuery + Ajax com Java EE

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Estou criando uma conexão com o banco em Java assim:

```
try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/projeto","postgres","754753"); 
        if(request.getParameter("user") != null)
        {
            //caminho para chegar até a tabela no BD
            Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from login where log_usuario = '"+
                    request.getParameter("user")+"' and log_senha = '"+
                    request.getParameter("pass")+"'");

            if(rs.next())
                //response.sendRedirect("paginas/home.jsp");
            else
                out.println("Não Logado");
        }

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ClassError){
        out.println("Driver não encontrado "+ClassError);
    }
    catch(SQLException SQLError){
        out.println("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados");
    }
```

Quero mandar para o ajax para ele validar com o `$.ajax({});`.

Dentro do `success` quero ter 3 condições que seriam:

1. informe seu usuário e senha
2. usuário ou senha inválidos
3. login efetuado, aguarde...

Mais ou menos assim:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
            var login = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:
                data:
                type:
                success: function(resposta){
                    if(resposta == 'erroempty'){
                        $('.msg').empty().hmtl('<p class="aviso">Informe seu usuário e senha!</p>').fadeIn('slow');
                    }else if(resposta == 'errosenha'){
                        $('.msg').empty().hmtl('<p class="erro">Erro ao logar! Dados não conferem!</p>').fadeIn('slow');
                    }else if(resposta == 'success'){
                        $('.msg').empty().hmtl('<p class="sucesso">Login efetuado, aguarde...</p>').fadeIn('slow');
                    }

                },
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.loginbox h1 img').fadeIn('fast');  
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('.loginbox h1 img').fadeOut('fast');  
                }


            });

            return false;

        });
```

Como faço para o Java passar as 3 informações (erroempty, errosenha e success) e o que eu colocaria em `url`, `data` e `type`?

Answer (score 1):

Então, seu problema é conceitual, você precisa entender como esse mecanismo de requests funciona, você poderia usar [JSON](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-java-o-pacote-org-json/25480) para retornar diversos parâmetros na pagina.

Exemplo de uso JSON no seu caso:

```
{
  "erroempty": {
    "Msg": "Informe seu usuário e senha!"
  },
  "errosenha": {
    "Msg": "Erro ao logar! Dados não conferem!"
  },
  "success": {
    "Msg": "Login efetuado, aguarde..."
  }
}
```

Configurando a request

```
 url:  destino da request
    data: Conjuntos de parâmetros que vão ser enviados via get/post
    type: tipo da request get/post
```

no seu caso!

```
url: Nome da classe principal onde está localizando seu primeiro exemplo
data:login
type: 'POST
```

Olhe a documentação do  [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Entendi, então eu coloco assim: url:    'index.jsp', data:   login, type:   'POST', mas sobre a questão da resposta do banco de dados, como faço para retornar um valor para o ajax dizendo se o usuário e senha estam certos ou não? pois é necessárias usar o metodo $.ajax({})

Comment: no retorno da query, você pode usar aquele  para enviar o objeto JSON, if(rs.next()) { enviar objeto aqui}

Comment: Obrigado por responder, então... eu não sei como eu faço para enviar, poderia me dar umas dicas, como eu poderia fazer para enviar?